# How can I turn my div content to responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

In my project, I'm using the top nav menu(purple part) and the left menu(pink part) as a layout to my views which you can see in the image. But when ı delete some contents from view, the left pink menu stay still long through the bottom. So it makes many empty white spaces at the bottom of my page. I want to make it responsive. I want it to be as long as the content. I'm not good with frontend so Idk is this about HTML or CSS. I made search but ı can't find the right keywords about my problem. I hope ı explained the problem clear :/

My view; [image]

**My problem part;**

[image]

**and HTML code of that pink part;**

```
        <div class="col-md-3 top-nav">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><h1>Alperen Öz</h1></a>
            </div>
            <div class="top-menu">
                <span class="menu"> </span>

                <ul class="cl-effect-16">
                    <li><a class="active" href=""~/Homepage/home" data-hover="Anasayfa">Anasayfa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-hover="Fotoğraf Galerisi">Fotoğraf Galerisi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-hover="Hakkımda">Hakkımda</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- script-for-nav -->
                <!-- script-for-nav -->
                <ul class="side-icons">
                    <li><a class="fb" href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="twitt" href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="goog" href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="drib" href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        @RenderBody()
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
```

thx in advance :)

Comment: Are you able to make an example we can run? That way we can inspect the CSS and how it's rendering the page. Without it it's hard to tell what causes the issue.

Comment: You can add your question's code snippets with using ctrl+m to make more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

U should put both this menu div and div with view in the same parent div and set `top-nav` `height: 100%`. So when you delete a view the parent element will also shrink its height so 100% will be now smaller than it was when the view was inside and when u'll add a new one, it will grow bigger so u will get this pink color bar on the left as well :D

Comment: I added  `height: 100%.` to the `top-nav` part like this. `<div style="height: 100%" class="col-md-3 top-nav">` empty white space got smaller but there's still some empty area. It doesn't fit full :/

Comment: Can u prepare a codepen with both styles and html for this site? I will try to figure it out